# Update td block with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html table, and i have assigned an id to one of the td blocks. It contains an image. How can I, using plain JavaScript, clear the image that is currently in the td block, and update it with another image.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some jQuery to do just that:

```
function updateImage(imageURL) {
    $("#cellID img").attr("src", imageURL);
}
```

And the pure JS without jQuery:

```
function updateImage(imageURL) {
    var tdElement = document.getElementById("cellID");
    var imgElements = tdElement.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var imgElement = imgElements[0];
    imgElement.src = imageURL;
}
```

Or more simply:

```
function updateImage(imageURL) {
    (document.getElementById("cellID").getElementsByTagName("img")[0]).src = imageURL;
}
```

Comment: Note this doesn't actually remove the image and add another one; it just switches the existing element's `src` attribute.  But the effect is the same, unless you had event handlers attached or something.

Comment: @cHao right. I assumed that by "clear the image and update it" he meant simply to replace it.

Comment: Is there a purely js way to do this? I know jquery is a javascript library, but can I use standard js to do this?

Comment: I get an error on the 1st line of the updateImage() method: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementByID'

Comment: @user1154644 sorry. A lower-case "d" in "Id" was intended.